# iOS/Mac development, problems using CFilter

Tags: iphone, ios

I am learning to program on iOS, and was learning some Core Image filters.

I learnt to use CIFilter as:

```
CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CISepiaTone" keysAndValues:kCIInputImageKey, image, @"inputIntensity", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.8], nil];

CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorPosterize" keysAndValues:kCIInputImageKey, image, @"inputLevels", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:5.0], nil];

CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIPointillize" keysAndValues:kCIInputImageKey, image, @"inputRadius", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:50.0], @"inputCenter", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:50.0], nil];
```

When I use CISepiaTone filter, the filter works and I get a nice transformed image output. But with other two filters, I do now get any output, the ImageView is blank. Can anyone spot the problem for me? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Core Image in iOS 5 doesn't support all of the filters listed in the Core Image filters reference.  You're probably trying to use filters that aren't supported.

`[CIFilter filterNamesInCategories:nil]` returns an `NSArray` containing the names of every available filter.

Comment: Thanks. hmm, how do I know which filters are supported in iOS 5?